# bring browser window to foreground via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, monitoring, dashboard

I am building a monitoring dashboard which uses webservices to do several unix script based server checks. 
Then the results are beautified in a dashboard format for user display.

Now, we have a server check which is very critical, and at the moment, the logic flashes a div in red. 
In the same event I need some sort of javascript/jquery code which will automatically bring the browser window having the dashboard into foreground even if the user is using other applications like outlook, office, other browser windows.

Comment: clarification: The unix based checks are done via webapps running in server end. My query is purely based on window focus in client end

Comment: Not possible. Otherwise every single spammer in the universe would be cramming their crap in your face, no matter what you've done with the browser window.

Comment: Maybe the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API) will be of use.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. I think Notification API will do the job perfectly.

Comment: @MarcB Your point is very valid. We do not want spammers infinitely stopping our work.